# Sound vibrations for marine propulsion

Tags: waves, acoustics, water

I asked a similar question about bubbles making less friction on a mass moving through water, now I'm wondering of sound waves could do the same thing as supercavitation or possibly create it's own propulsion with the right combination of frequencies.

Comment: Propulsion requires net momentum exchange. While this is possible with sound waves, the efficiency is probably rather low. Creating a large amount of gas in water is not a problem since one can generate steam. There is probably a critical velocity beyond which any object of suitable shape will automatically create its own supercavitating bubble. The only question is how much power it takes to reach that velocity?

Comment: Cavitation effects can be caused by very intense sound waves. However, it seems unlikely they could be used to reduce friction. They tend to be very destructive since upon collapsing enormous temperature and pressure can arise.

Comment: @DirkBruere what do you mean by intense? Amplitude, frequency? If a sound wave is repeated at the proper time and power, would that deal with the 'destructive' outcome?

Comment: Surely there's a shrimp which can do this?

Comment: This link will explain ultrasonic cavitation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation

Comment: Very nice, respect to the shrimp.